# Beanstalkd stats show jobs but peek-ready is not found

Tags: beanstalkd

I've got a Beanstalkd instance running and can put jobs on the queue without problems.

I can see the jobs are there:

```
$ echo -e "stats\r\n" | nc localhost 11300 | grep jobs

current-jobs-urgent: 0
current-jobs-ready: 3
current-jobs-reserved: 0
current-jobs-delayed: 0
current-jobs-buried: 0
total-jobs: 3
```

But trying to pull them off with an application fails, as does trying to see one with peek-ready:

```
$ echo -e "peek-ready\r\n" | nc localhost 11300

NOT_FOUND
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: install this admin interface and you will see where your jobs are https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s quite possible the jobs are on a different (non-default) tube that you are not USEing.

> The peek commands let the client inspect a job in the system. There are four variations. All but the first operate only on the currently used tube.

You can see how many different tubes exist (beyond the tube named `default`) with the `current-tubes` that is also returned from the `stats` command, and the `list-tubes` command, that will list them.When you know which tube(s) the jobs are on, you can `use {tube-name}`, and then `peek-ready` on the  tube.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that you need to `use {tube-name}` to `peek-ready`, but `watch {tube-name}` to reserve. I wasted a lot of time thinking `peek-ready` operated on the watched tube.